# Por que no se guardan datos en mis listas?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa que verifica si hay números primos o no, y a los primos los quiero guardar en un array y a los que no, también. El problema es que no lo hacen, hay números que no los lee o solo lee el ultimo.Ya intente de todas las maneras posibles, appendeando el indice, la variable definida, todo.

```
opcion = 1
numeros = []

while opcion !=0:
    numero = int(input("Ingrese un numero: "))
    numeros.append(numero)
    primos = []
    noPrimos = []
    def PRIMOS(numero):
        for i in range(2,numero):
            if (numero % i) == 0:
                noPrimos.append(i)
                print ("No primos")
            return False 

        else:
            primos.append(i) #tambien intente con la variable numero, y tampoco
            print("Primos")
            return True
    PRIMOS(numero)   

opcion = int(input ("0 salir | 1 continuar: "))

print(numeros) 
print(primos)
print(noPrimos)
#Al ejecutar esto, solo me devuelve el ultimo valor leido o no me devuelve nada ([])
```

Comment: Porque las listas las creas adentro del `while` en cada iteración se crea una lista vacía. Además opción nunca se va a ejecutar porque está afuera del `while`.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, se me habia escapado ese detalle importante.

Answer (score 0):

Errores:

1. Las funciones se define en el nivel superior del programa.
2. El número que debes guardar es `numero` (lo que estás probando) y no `i`.
3. El `else` está mal anidado. Tal como está, corresponde al `for`, no al `if`.
4. El patrón usual es usar `while True:` y adentro preguntar si es hora de salir y terminar.
5. Vuelves a crear las listas en cada iteración ...

*Código revisado*

```
opcion = 1
numeros = []
primos = []
noPrimos = []


def PRIMOS(numero):
    for i in range(2, numero):
        if (numero % i) == 0:
            noPrimos.append(numero)
            print("No primos")
            return False
        else:
            primos.append(numero)  # tambien intente con la variable numero, y tampoco
            print("Primos")
            return True

while True:
    numero = int(input("Ingrese un numero: "))
    if numero == 0:
        break

    numeros.append(numero)
    PRIMOS(numero)

opcion = int(input ("0 salir | 1 continuar: "))

print(numeros)
print(primos)
print(noPrimos)
```

produce:

```
Ingrese un numero: 3
Primos
Ingrese un numero: 4
No primos
Ingrese un numero: 5
Primos
Ingrese un numero: 6
No primos
Ingrese un numero: 7
Primos
Ingrese un numero: 8
No primos
Ingrese un numero: 9
Primos
Ingrese un numero: 10
No primos
Ingrese un numero: 11
Primos
Ingrese un numero: 12
No primos
Ingrese un numero: 13
Primos
Ingrese un numero: 0
0 salir | 1 continuar: 0
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
[4, 6, 8, 10, 12]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!! ahora funciona!